# How to manage axis x with two different data sets

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I make a line graph if I have two different data sets for axis x?

On my x axis there will be "materials" (as the main) and at the same time I also need to add in "weeks".

Answer (score 0):

You can always convert one of your data sets to run on a secondary axis; this is normally done when you have very different *types* of data, such as comparing absolute values to percentages.

Once your chart is created, you can right-click on one of your data series and choose "Format Axis" (or, alternatively, go to Chart Tools | Layout, use the dropdown on the far left to select your data series, and choose "Format Selection").

On the "Series Options" section, you'll see a radio button where you can select "Primary Axis" or "Secondary Axis". Select Secondary Axis, and your data will be plotted on two different axes with scales appropriate to the values.

Note that, because the data will actually overlap across the category axis, it's advisable for at least one of your data series to be a line or similar, rather than a column chart.